# Open windows get stuck in launcher

Tags: launcher, window, application-switcher

It often happens to me that a minimized window can not be opened again. 
This applies to all the programs I am using (PyCharm, Google Chrome, Spotify, Terminal, ...) and to any situation, e.g.:

- right after opening (the program opens as a window and then disappears and remains only in Launcher)
- after minimizing the window
- after covering the window with another open window

What doesnt help:

- clicking on the icon in Launcher (though the icon still signalizes that the program is running)
- Alt+Tab (the same situation)
- upgrading Ubuntu (I had this problem even on Ubuntu 16.10)

What sometimes helps:

- quitting the program (right click on the Launcher icon) and starting again
- restarting the computer

I am running Ubuntu 17.04, Acer Aspire V15 Nitro.

**Example: Output of `wmctrl -lG`**

```
0x02c00002  0 -2020 -1180 1920 1080 Maggie XdndCollectionWindowImp  
0x02c00003  0 0    24   65   1056 Maggie unity-launcher  
0x02c00004  0 0    0    1920 24   Maggie unity-panel  
0x02c00005  0 -420 -300 320  200  Maggie unity-dash  
0x02c00006  0 -420 -300 320  200  Maggie Hud  
0x0260000a -1 0    0    3840 1080 Maggie Desktop  
0x04600041  0 3905 62   1849 1004 Maggie meter-reader - [~/gf/meter-reader] - segmentation_net.py - PyCharm Community Edition 2017.2  
0x02e00039  0 436  74   1113 845  Maggie Slack - Cognexa  
0x03a00021  0 1985 24   1855 1056 Maggie Open windows get stuck in launcher - Ask Ubuntu - Google Chrome  
0x05000006  0 65   346  734  410  Maggie marek@Maggie: ~  
0x02c0000b  0 1920 24   65   1056 Maggie unity-launcher  
0x02c0000c  0 1920 0    1920 24   Maggie unity-panel
```

The program that got stuck is **meter-reader - [~/gf/meter-reader] - segmentation_net.py - PyCharm Community Edition 2017.2**

After that, forcing the window to open through `wmctrl -ir 0x04600041 -e 0,100,100,500,500` helps. But this solves just the symptom, the problem then appears again next time.

Output of *xrandr*:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 345mm x 194mm
   1920x1080     60.02*+  59.93  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   960x600       60.00  
   960x540       59.99  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   576x432       60.06  
   512x384       60.00  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   320x240       60.05  
DP-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1-1 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 531mm x 299mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x576i      50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x480i      60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DP-1-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: To find out, could you install wmctrl (`sudo apt-get install wmctrl`), and, if the issue occurs again, run `wmctrl -lG` in a terminal, add the output to your question. Could you also @ping me if you do?

Comment: @JacobVlijm thanks for reaction. I added the wmctrl output

Comment: Thanks a lot! the window seems to be off the visible area, unless you have a really huge screen :). If you still have it running, does the command `wmctrl -ir 0x046000416 -e 0,100,100,500,500` bring it back? (where `0x046000416` is the window id of the lost window)

Comment: Oh yeah, and please also add the output of `xrandr` to the question.

Comment: @JacobVlijm i added the info you mentioned. the fix works for one time, but the issue still stays - some window gets stuck from time to time.

Comment: I am on the way, will answer later, last question: do you have an external screen attached, but switched off?

Comment: @JacobVlijm external screen is attached and switched ON (at the time of the example `wimctrl` printout). When it is off and i turn it on again, I feel that there is higher probabiliy that the window gets stuck, however.